# A concept of adjoint of endomorphisms of a finite dimensional vector space $V$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was looking at one problem. Part of description of problem is that

Let R be a commutative ring of endomorphisms of a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over $C$ with hermitian inner product. Suppose that $R$ is closed under taking adjoints with respect to the inner product....

I do not understand how to interpret the condition '$R$ is closed under taking adjoints with respect to the inner product'

If we to use language of matrices, does that say a set of matrices with $A$ and $A^{*}$ both in the group? Is that relevant to inner product?

Comment: How do you define adjoints, if not using an inner product?

Comment: From context I can see that you don't mean "a group of matrices" in the group theory sense, but I think it would be a bit clearer if you said "a set of matrices..."

Comment: Yes, I should use a set of.

Comment: Thanks!. I think I know what you mean now. I usually just think of matrices and their conjugate transpose without thinking of the inner product. But what you said is definitely true.

Answer (score 1):

To clear things up, generally speaking we have the following. If $V, W$ are inner product spaces and $T : V \to W$ a linear transformation, then the *[adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint) of $T$ with respect to these inner products* is the unique (if it exists) linear transformation $T^{\dagger} : W \to V$ satisfying

$$\langle Tv, w \rangle_W = \langle v, T^{\dagger} w \rangle_V$$

for all $v \in V, w \in W$. If $V = \mathbb{R}^n, W = \mathbb{R}^m$ equipped with the usual inner products then this reduces to the usual transpose, and if $V = \mathbb{C}^n, W = \mathbb{C}^m$ equipped with the usual inner products then this reduces to the usual conjugate transpose. But it's worth knowing that if you picked a different inner product the adjoint operation would change, and it's also worth knowing that this definition generalizes smoothly to the infinite-dimensional case.

So yes, concretely the definition says that $R$ is a commutative subring of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ closed under conjugate transpose.